# Use Saml2 or Ws Federation to authenticate on IDM SAP and ADFS

Tags: asp.net-core, saml, ws-federation, sustainsys-saml2

Recently I've got a new demand in which I need to let the user authenticate in my application IDM SAP. Previously I had to integrate my application with ADFS. 
In order to do that I used Ws Federation, and the application runs on Asp Net Core.
The authentication with ADFS works just fine, on StartUp I make my application retrieve the metadata XML file from the Idp server. Then I redirect the user to the Idp login page, it validates if the the authentication worked, returns the response, and then open my application.

Now, I've done some research to understand how I would do the same with IDM SAP. I've got a bit confused when I saw articles comparing SAML to WS Federation. What makes it even more confusing to me is that the client already provided his xml metadata file, and it looks very similar to the other one that uses ADFS.

Here's how I implemented Ws Federation:

```
services
                    .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                    {
                        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddWsFederation(options =>
                    {
                        options.Wtrealm = appSettings.Adfs.Wtrealm;
                        options.MetadataAddress = appSettings.Adfs.MetadataAddress;
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    })
                    .AddCookie();
```

**The Idp URL is located in my appSettings file.**

It came to my mind I should try to read this new XML file provided from a local folder, but this property "MetadataAddress" seems to always expect only URLs. The IDM Sap user already said they won't expose their XML file, so I'll have to always read from a local xml file.

It didn't work, so now I'm trying to figure if my option will be to implement more than one protocol in my application.

So far I found this library that seems to be the solution
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/master/Samples/SampleAspNetCore2ApplicationNETFramework/Startup.cs

I've got stuck when trying to set the XML file on StartUp method, This is what I'm trying:

```
                    .AddSaml2(options =>
                    {
                        options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("mine.metadata.xml");
                        options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                            new IdentityProvider(
                                new EntityId("mine.metadata.xml"), options.SPOptions)
                            {
                                LoadMetadata = true
                            });

                        options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"mine.metadata.xml"));
                    })
```

It returns me an error when trying to set the service certificate saying that it couldn't find the file specified.

Also, let's pretend I set the configuration. How should I redirect the user to IDM Sap login page?

Could anyone give some advice or guidance so I can create a better solution that works for both cases?

Comment: What is `mine.metadata.xml`? For `X509Certificate2`, you need to pass a valid certificate file. For login page, you could try to set `IdentityProvider.SingleSignOnServiceUrl` during `new IdentityProvider`.

Comment: @TaoZhou "mine.metadata.xml" is just a name a made up for a file that would be the medatada we need to retrieve from a given URL passing to the property "MetaDataAddress". I'm having a hard time trying to make my code read it locally. Would you have any reference that does something like it? My problem here is that I don't know what I should pass instead of using the property "MetaDataAddress"

Comment: You can't. This is by design, you could check [entityId](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/config-elements/sustainsys-saml2.html#attributes)